# How do I deal with an Umbral Sight Ranger's enormous advantages in Curse of Strahd?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, encounter-design, invisibility

I'm playing the module *Curse of Strahd*. The Tabaxi Ranger with the Umbral Sight ability causes a lot of problems.

Fights take place in dark rooms or at night. Almost all undead have darkvision, but the ranger's ability allows him to remain invisible to darkvision in almost all battles. Creating a light source also does not help, because of the high mobility, the ranger simply moves beyond the radius of illumination.

How to counter this? Please share your experience.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Rictavio, take the [tour] when you have a moment. We're going to need some more information before we can answer your question. What problems are they causing? Why do you want to counter them?

Comment: You might also find some helpful guidance for asking in these [help] articles: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm pretty sure he is not a native speaker and "Shadow Gaze" is Umbral Sight, and the Ranger is a Doom Stalker that hence is invisible in darkness, and  has good movement as it also is a Tabaxi. He does not know how to handle it. They are playing Curse of Strahd. Related: [Is Gloom Stalker Overpowered](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/195749/is-gloom-stalker-overpowered)

Comment: what exactly is the problem you have with this PC?

Comment: I see you've added some more information, thanks for that. It still isn't clear to me what problem this is causing, you've just described how the character's features work. Are you having trouble designing appropriately challenging encounters for the party and suspect the ranger's features are the reason? We need to know more than just how the features work, we need to know specifically *what problems or challenges are the ranger's features causing for you?*

Comment: My guess, and it's not always easy to express (and I'd love confirmation) is that the ranger is disproportionate powerful and isn't challenged in combat encounters. I'm taking that mostly from the phrasing of "How to counter this?". Possibly just for future reference, there's a lot of *other* problems when running (against) a specific character (certain info being hard to track, things taking too long, etc.) so it's very useful to be as clear as possible.

Comment: I believe that OP is running an adventure that uses night or dungeon fights with enemies that usually don't get impacted, but this one PC is pretty much permanently invisible... I believe it is about help with encounter design.

Comment: Yes, we have a gloom stallker in our group too, and it caused the exact same issues (ours also is a rogue, so gets bonus action dash and hide, even nastier). I won't answer in comments here, but I think I have a pretty good idea what the issue here is, and also of course a few ideas on how to counter it. I guess they are using an italian or such rulebook, and the querant is translating the names of features as best they can into English, but unaware of the official, English name.

Comment: I have edited your question to use the correct English terms for the various features. Please undo if you think this is not correct. Also, can you please confirm that your problem is how to create encounters that are challenging for the whole party, inlcuding the ranger, in spite of their ability? I think it is, but it is not 100% clear from the question.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin If you think it isn’t clear what the problem is, why did you vote to reopen? It was closed for “needs details or clarity”, and reopening then leaving a comment saying it needs details or clarity seems…strange.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I think it is pretty clear what the issue is. I am refraining from answering mostly to not annoy you, as you seem to feel very strongly that there is not enough information here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141899/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-groody-the-hobgoblin).

Comment: I’d already voted to reclose before the change, but I’m always wary about making sweeping changes to an unclear question and leaving it as latest. It may be better to roll back and let OP confirm before we try and answer a question they may not have asked. Either way, I think we still need to know which advantages are concerning and hopefully details around them.