# Can a Gloom Stalker Ranger (potentially) make an attack roll five times in one turn via the Attack action?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, actions, ranger

As the DM, a player at my table is playing a Gloom Stalker Ranger, at level 11. This player  was able to make an attack on their first turn of combat while utilising two-weapon fighting, per the PHB rules. The player chose to used "Dread Ambusher" on the first attack, missed the second attack granted by extra attack and then used "Stalker's Flurry" as well as their bonus action attack from two weapon fighting. Do these features actually stack like this, or did I make a mistake in allowing this?

> **Two-Weapon Fighting**
> When you take the attack action with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand. you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand, you don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.

> **Extra Attack**
> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

> **Dread Ambusher**
> At the start of your first turn of each combat, your walking speed increases by 10 feet, which lasts until the end of that turn. If you take the Attack action on that turn, you can make one additional weapon attack as part of that action. If that attack hits, the target takes an extra 1d8 damage of the weapon's damage type.

Comment: Highly related: [Is Gloom Stalker overpowered?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/195749/75095)

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin That question is largely about the Umbral Sight feature. I don't think it is as related as it could be, and should probably be renamed to be more specific

Comment: @DavidCoffron Yes, maybe only related, not highly related. The outcome of the answers is that it is not Umbral Sigh per se, it is the optimization in a dark environment *and* the fact they get to make a lot of attacks, too.

Comment: I count 5... 1+ea+da+sf+ba, but only if one missed

Comment: @Wyrmwood you are indeed correct, will revise that now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes, they can make 4 attacks (5 if they miss)

1. Attack Action, due to Extra Attack = 2 attacks
2. Use Bonus Action to make 2-Weapon Fighting attack when taking the Attack action (with appropriate weapons; only one bonus action per turn)
3. They took the Attack Action, so they get to make a 4th attack with Dread Ambusher. This is not a bonus action, so there is no conflict with 2.

Your interpretation is right.

Stalker's Flurry says:

> Once on each of your turns when you miss with a weapon attack, you can make another weapon attack as part of the same action.

So if they miss with any of those attacks, they can try again once for a fifth attack. Since this again is not a bonus attack, there is no conflict in combining it.

If they had two levels in Fighter for Action Surge, they could even take another Attack action, to repeat point 1. and 3. for a total of 7 attacks.

Comment: I have a high level Gloom Stalker/Fighter character that I made for a one-shot. The DM ruled that the extra attack from Dread Ambusher couldn't be applied to a second attack action from Action Surge. But you are right, RAW it should have been allowed.